# t.replace is not a function in selenium RC

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, payment-gateway

I am using selenium 2.25 with firefox 3.6 and I am facing issues when i run my scripts.

Below is the error in my console and system displaying alert message as `"Type error $j undefined"`

```
ERROR: Command execution failure. Please search the forum at http://clearspace.openqa.org for error details from the log window.  The error message is: t.replace is not a function
```

May I know what is the problem here, the scripts which I used were running fine earlier, but from last week eclipse showing error as above when I run my scripts.

Selenium version:2.25

OS:Windows 7.0

Browser:Firefox

Browser version:3.6

Comment: for more details click on this link
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4299#c15

Answer (score 0):

t.replace is not a function is normally caused by trying to perform a replace on a null in JavaScript.

I suspect you are trying to interact with something on the page before all the JavaScript has finished loading and this is causing the error.  This will be intermittant because sometimes the page will have fully loaded and the JavaScript on the page will have processed correctly. whilst at other times Selenium may get in there a bit too quickly.

Generally have your devs check their javaScript code, there is a path that results in a replace being performed on a null.  They should have some code to protect against things like this, it's caused by bad quality code.

Basically you have found a bug.